# ST3 regex to find number sequences not surrounded by other characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, plaintext

Forgive the possibly question as I'm fairly new to formulating my own regex, and anything that I've come up with, I've done so in the past hour.

I have a huge text file that I'm working with in Sublime Text 3. I'm attempting to use regular expressions in ST's Search and Replace feature to identify **all 2-4 digit sequences** that are **not surrounded by any other characters**.

This would identify the following sequences:

```
01
330
0302
```

And ignore the following:

```
1
10405
3042-2
(3030
x5590
```

In the context of my document, a sequence not being surrounded by any other characters essentially means existing on its own line.

So in other words, **if a 2-4 digit sequence exists on its own line, it needs to be identified. If not, or if it's <2 or >5 digits, it needs to be left alone.**

The best I've been able to come up with so far is this:

`\b\n[0-9]{2,4}\n\b`

...which works for the identification of those sequences well enough, but doesn't actually seem to allow me to replace the identified area: clicking Replace or pressing the shortcut *Ctrl+Shift+H* only seems to highlight the sequences and then move on. If this *is* a problem with the regex I am using, what else can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too clear on what you are asking, but if you want to match 2-4 digits on a line by itself, this should do it

```
^[0-9]{2,4}$
```

The ^ matches begin of line, $ matches end

If you want to allow for leading or trailing spaces, you can do this

```
^[ ]*[0-9]{2,4}[ ]*$
```

What do you want to replace the text with?  If say you want delete the matched text and the whole line, you can do this

```
^[0-9]{2,4}$\n
```

This matches the entire line including the newline.

Alternatively, you can capture the matched text with parentheses

```
^([0-9]{2,4})$
```

and do a replace like this

```
foo$1bar
```

The $1 is whatever is in the (...).  This will give you

```
foo01bar
foo330bar
foo0302bar

And ignore the following:

1
10405
3042-2
(3030
x5590
```

Comment: I think you might have slightly misunderstood what I was asking for with my examples, but never mind; this answer is perfect. The first regex answers exactly what I was asking for, and the second with the `\n` goes further and saves me the extra step of deleting the blank lines that the first solution - and my own - leave behind. Thanks so much.